# Can deleted answers be hidden by default with something to click to show them?

Tags: feature-request, deleted-answers

Usually deleted answers are not particularly useful, which is why they were deleted.  If they were hidden (compacted to the first line) by default with a JS [+] to expand them there would be less noise for 10K users.

Comment: If no one has made a GreaseMonkey script for this already, it probably wouldn't take much to make one.

Comment: I'd recommend people should have to "opt-in" via a checkbox that appears on their preferences tab.  That way you could set your default and not have to open or close the `[+]` all the time if its default state isn't to your liking.

Comment: I'll happily make you a greasemonkey script... first you just need to go to my SO profile & upvote everything I've posted until I reach 10k so I can test it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I however agree that deleted answers only adds noise. As you see in the *Related* list on the right column, the same problem was discussed before a lot times. Either by removing them from the view, or just pushing them to the entire bottom. Most of those questions got a lot of votes, so there's certainly support from the community.

Bill made a very good point in his comment: make it a preference. The <10K users already don't see them, so this logic is already implemented in the business/view side. Implementing an extra preference seems little effort for the dev team and big favour for the >10K community.

I personally, however, got used to them. I just scoll ahead. But I can find myself in your problem when I went over 10K some months ago.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of like seeing the deleted answers, sometimes they're interesting to read and I think if there were a method of expansion I'd be frustrated at having to expand them all the time just to satisfy my own curiosity/nosiness.

The deleted answers are well highlighted, the different colour makes it easy to differentiate between answers worth reading and answers you don't need to bother with.

For those reasons I disagree (-1).