# Give moderators the ability to restore those accidentally deleted comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, moderator-abilities, deleted-comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Moderators should be able to undelete comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98036/moderators-should-be-able-to-undelete-comments)

[Viewing deleted comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85442/allow-moderators-to-see-deleted-comments) was implemented, now what about being able to restore them?

As far as I'm concerned, make it a simple button on the same form where we can see the deleted ones.

Comment: Accidentally? @_@

Comment: This would save us some hassle when we need to delete 20 comments and save one.

Comment: @RobertHarvey just ask JackDouglas ;-)

Comment: Whoops ... go me (/facepalm). Dupe!