# Are my deleted comments visible to others?

Tags: support, comments, deleted-comments

I have deleted my comments. Can other users see those deleted comments, for example users with a certain amount of reputation or moderators?

Comment: Diamond mods can see the deleted comments - I do not believe that 10K+ users can do this - correct me if I'm wrong...

Comment: who are Diamond mods what thier reputation criteria

Comment: @kishorejangid [Who are the diamond moderators, and what is their role?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/who-are-the-diamond-moderators-and-what-is-their-role)

Comment: And [this particular link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85442/allow-moderators-to-see-deleted-comments) suggests that mods (now) can see deleted comments.

Comment: @Bart - we can, but only if we select the "view deleted comments" option.

Comment: @ChrisF I just clicked a link to "discussion" and my deleted comments showed up in the discussion. And I cannot delete them there, only flag them. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 26):

Diamond moderators (elected or appointed by SE) can see deleted comments. They are still hidden by default, a moderator has to explicitly go looking for them.

Normal users, even with high reputation, cannot see deleted comments.