# Why can only mods see deleted comments?

Tags: discussion, privileges, moderator-abilities, deleted-comments

Only mods can see deleted comments

- [Allow moderators to see deleted comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85442/allow-moderators-to-see-deleted-comments)
- [Are my deleted comments visible to others?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126351/are-my-deleted-comments-visible-to-others)
- [Do 10k users get to read deleted comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32651/do-10k-users-get-to-read-deleted-comments)

Why can only mods see deleted comments, but any user with sufficiently high rep can see deleted questions and answers?

I am *not* saying this is a bad idea. (Though if you think it is, I'd love to know why.) I am curious what the significant difference between questions/answers and comments is in this respect.

My current thoughts:

**Advantage:** Most deleted comments are garbage.

**Disadvantage:** There isn't any real way to "audit" or discuss moderator behavior, as with deleted posts. This cascades into other areas, such as the decision to lock a post because of (deleted) off-topic comments (see [How many off-topic comments does this have?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255850/how-many-off-topic-comments-does-this-have)).

In my limited experience most deleted posts are garbage too. What is the significant difference?

Comment: [Shog's explanation.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/225189)

Comment: Well, comments are second-rate citizens in comparison to posts. In addition, most deleted comments are either a) offensive, b) off-topic, or c) obsolete. So do you *really* want to see that?

Comment: @animuson, to summarize Shog's post, implementing it just isn't a priority because of lack of value.

Comment: @hichris123, true, but *delete posts* are a) offensive, b) off-topic, or c) obsolete. Why would you really want to see that?

Comment: @PaulDraper Meh. I don't really see a need to see deleted-comments most of the time... and also, see my first comment: comments are second-rate citizens. They're not designed to stay around long. Therefore, spending time to show deleted ones seems a bit... odd. We do need a better flagging system for comments though.

Comment: Also, [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/182094/237685).

Comment: @PaulDraper One reason could be that deleted posts contribute to bans; comments do not. Hence, users who have had their posts deleted need to be able to see it to understand the problem, improve them, and get out of the ban.