# Broken highlighting on deleted comments

Tags: bug, comments, moderator-tools, deleted-comments

There is a minor bug in the display of deleted comments (visible to ♦ moderators and SE staff only) that is, well, bugging me.

## Background

[Moderators can see deleted comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/85469/238426), which is very handy when we're trying to evaluate certain flags and evaluating whether or not a user is being abusive in some way. Unfortunately, the view for deleted comments seems to have a bug.

Ordinarily user display names in certain on-screen elements—flair below a post, comments, edits in a post's revision history and certain "deleted by" blurbs—get a special background if the action was by OP, like these examples:

[image] [image]

On SO Main, the highlighting happens to be blue, but it varies by site. Other users—that is, anyone other than OP for a given question—aren't highlighted.

## The Problem

When comments by OP get deleted by someone other than OP, the deleting user is given this OP-specific highlighting nonetheless. In other words, on each of OP's comments, the deletion user's display name has the highlighting, but on each comment by any other user, the deletion user does not have the highlighting. This seems to happen regardless of whether the deletion was by a ♦ moderator or because of flags on particularly bad comments.

I'd include a screenshot, but it's basically impossible without redacting it for privacy reasons to the point that the highlighting is hidden, anyway.

This is clearly not a major, site-breaking bug, but it is making life a little harder on moderators, or at least this one.

## Proposal

Please fix this! It seems like it's just an incorrect condition causing a `class` attribute to be given an incorrect value.

Comment: @MonicaCellio good find; I looked, but couldn't find anything about this. One distinction, though, is that it seems to be applying to flaggers as well as mods. Also, I would have sworn this was new behavior and that everything looked okay until a couple of weeks ago, though I definitely could be mistaken on that one.

Comment: I thought I remembered reporting this so went digging.  Not quite; what I remembered was adding some info in an answer on the other report.  If it's applying to flaggers, though, that might be different.  The behavior hasn't gone away for me since I posted there, but it sounds like behavior has varied over time and by site.